# Binding to a ValidationRule

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF user control in which I have a textbox. This is bound to a viewmodel which is generated during runtime.

My Viewmodel looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private readonly IValidationRule _validationRule;

    public MyViewModel(IValidationRule validationRule)
    {
        _validationRule = validationRule;
    }

    public IValidationRule ValidationRule { get; set; }
}

public interface IValidationRule
{
}

internal class MyValidationRule:ValidationRule,IValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I need to bind the property `ValidationRule` to the textbox. I could have done this easily like below by specyfying the type:

```
<TextBox Name="UploadsLoginsTextBox" MinWidth="30">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MaxUp" Mode="TwoWay" NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <Validators:MyValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

..but since my viewmodel and hence my validator is created dynamically I cannot do it. Is there a way by which I can do this in XAML. Something like binding the validation rule to the property in the viewmodel? Please note I'm using .NET 3.5.

Thanks,
-Mike